# How do I check if a country is at war?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I don't see a list of wars like in Europa Universalis, so how can I check if a country is at war?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three ways to see wars in CK2.

First, you can select the capital (or any other county) of the land you want to check. Under the portrait of the holder, there is a bar listing all the current wars, treaties and hostility of the selected county. You can hover over the icons to see who is participating, the goal of the war and the current warscore.

[image: county screen]

This list is also found on the diplomacy screen.

[image: diplomacy screen]

You can also open the ledger in the bottom right. Page 11 is a list of all wars in the world, with main participants, war score and start date listed.

[image: ledger screen]

If you need help visualizing where their adversary is, you can activate the diplomatic relation map mode and select their county. Their enemies will be colored red, and their allies are blue.

[image: Diplomatic relations]